# reading a line from a file and splitting it - python

Tags: python

I have a file with just 1 line of data ( close to 3 MB ) I need to split it into smaller lines and write the output to a new file.

for eg :

> sample.txt - file
>   434D012000100009362D00000000069E0F0007000000DA434D01030010010003008000000000000000000000009C434D01200010000
>   .... and so on

I want to split the whole line into smaller lines each of 23 bytes each.
ie how do i get to write a python script to tell break after so many characters

Thanks.

Comment: You read in 23 bytes at a time and then output them to another file with a newline at the end. Not rocket science.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use python? Not that it isn't possible, just that there's a convenient POSIX command that will do it for you already…

Comment: `man split` is your friend for a non-python-solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file in 23 byte chunks:

```
from functools import partial

with open('sample.txt', 'rb') as inputfile, open(outputfilename, 'wb') as output:
    for chunk in iter(partial(inputfile.read, 23), ''):
        # chunk is 23 bytes small
        output.write(chunk + '\n')
```

Here we use the [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) with a sentinel to loop over a function until that function returns `''`, the empty string. The function we loop over is using [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to call `inputfile.read()` with the argument 23 each and every time. You could use a lambda (`lambda: inputfile.read(23)`) instead, but `partial()` is a faster.

Comment: I can't tell if the file is really hex (in which case maybe the OP wants 46-char lines, or the first 23 bytes' worth of hex) or not.  The name `sample.txt` makes me think maybe it *is* hex, though.

Comment: @DSM: The post says '23 bytes', not '23 characters'.

Comment: @NoName: `434D` is 2 bytes or 4? Or to put it differently, is that the 2 binary values 0x43 and 0x4D in your file, or the 4 ASCII characters 4, 3, 4 and D, or 0x34, 0x33, 0x34, 0x44 in binary?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, but assuming the text file is made up of hex, I can't think of a good reason to want 11.5 bytes worth of data in different rows, and people aren't always very precise when they speak.. but your answer was accepted, so maybe I'm wrong. :^)

Comment: @DSM: The OP can always replace `23` with `46` if these are ASCII characters representing hex values. :-)

Comment: Well, I was also entertaining the idea that we were to turn `43` into `0x43`, which is a little trickier.  (Trivial, but you know what I mean.)

Comment: @DSM: Not really; just use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

Answer (score 0):

Use a function as a generator. I'm quite fond of the [array-module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html#module-array).

```
def bytesfromfile(f):
    while True:
        raw = array.array('c')
        raw.fromstring(f.read(23))
        if not raw:
            break
        yield raw
```

Use `'c'` to interpret the values as a character. `'B'` as an unsigned char i.e. 0-255.